# XMLHttpRequest querying couchdb: CORS headers set, but does not work

Tags: javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest, cors, couchdb

I have an apache up and running with a simple html page including java script to query data from couchdb server running on the same machine (but different port).

```
<script>
        updateHistory();

        function updateHistory() {
            var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

            Httpreq.open("GET", "http://192.168.178.43:5984/temp_data/_design/dataView/_view/getAll", false);
            Httpreq.send(null);

            console.log(Httpreq.responseText);
            var dataObj = JSON.parse(Httpreq.responseText);
            document.getElementById('data-id').innerHTML = Httpreq.responseText;
        }
</script>
```

I keep getting *cors header 'access-control-allow-origin' missing* error. So I added CORS Headers in my apache config.

```
    # Always set these headers.
    # origin must match exactly the URL in browser address bar
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

    # set all headers needed, wildcard does not work!
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Accept,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Connection,Content-Type,Cookie,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With"

    # set allowed methods (GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,..) or * for all
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "*"

    # allow credentials (cookies)
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

I verified in firefox... the headers are correctly set, but I keep getting the error. Right now I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Here the request header:

```
Host: 192.168.178.43
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 
Firefox/46.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://192.168.178.43/index.html
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

And the response...

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 497
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 13 Jun 2016 17:11:06 GMT
Etag: "352-5352bf8ecde14-gzip"
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jun 2016 17:10:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Accept,Accept-Charset,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Connection,Content-Type,Cookie,DNT,Host,Keep-Alive,Origin,Referer,User-Agent,X-CSRF-Token,X-Requested-With
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "So I added CORS Headers in my apache config" which apache config you are talking about ? I have the same issue from my side

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. I had to enable CORS on the couchdb server in the local.ini:

```
[httpd]
enable_cors = true

[cors]
origins = http://192.168.178.43
```